# Bitlength probabilities of the shortcut Collatz map

Tags: collatz-conjecture

If my calculations are right the probability that the next number in Collatz'sequence has increased its bitlength is equal to $31.25 \%$

*Bitlength meaning; the length from a fixed position of least significant bit equal to either $0$ or $1$ to the most significant bit that has only the value $1$.*

The results are done on the shortcut definition of the Collatz map.

I came up with this probability based on neighbouring bitpatterns. The first based on three pluss a past state yielding: $12.5\%$ for $\frac{3n+1}{2}$ if odd, and I included the probability $50\%$ for $\frac{n}{2}$ if even.

Are there any literature on the probabilities of the bitlength of numbers in Collatz sequence of the function $\frac{3n+1}{2} \text{ if } n \equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $\frac{n}{2} \text{ if } n \equiv 0 \mod 2$ ?

I would like to know if the percentage has been found anywhere else and/or is written in the literature so I can study what has been found. Or if someone could actually test this based on large amounts of initial numbers say up to $1000000$?

If the percentages are correct it also suggest heuristically that there is an orbit trending towards $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Just an image of the distribution over 200 experiments of your probability-value $ ~31.25% $ (my overall result for 200 experiments is $33.338$)

where *one experiment* means:

$1\,000\, 000$ random numbers $ x_1 \lt 2^{31}$ are tested, from where the probability of increase by one or more bits $\text{binary_length}(x_2) \gt \text{binary_length}(x_1)$ is documented.  See the image below

[image]

(data generated in about one minute using Pari/GP)

```
N=1 000 000;
{list=vectorv(200);il=0;
for(j=1,#list,
     su=0;for(k=1,N,
                     m1=100+random(2^31); \\ use numbers >=100
                     if( m1 % 2
                             , m2=(3*m1+1)/2
                             , m2=m1/2
                        );
                     l1=#binary(m1);
                     l2=#binary(m2);
                     su += (l2>l1)
                );
      il++;
      list[il] = su / N *100.0; \\ put the new result into the list
     );
     print(list); }  \\ the aggregation of data for frequencies-table
                     \\ has been done outside of Pari/GP
```

---

The following picture is for the $3n+1; n/2$ version.

[image: imaga]

---

Data

```
(3n+1)/2  3n+1
----------------
33.3388 50.0108   based on 1 000 000 random values x1 with 100<x1<2^31
33.3496 50.0005   based on 1 000 000 random values x1 with 100<x1<2^31
33.2132 49.9454   based on 1 000 000 random values x1 with 100<x1<2^31
33.3905 50.0393   ... 
33.3528 49.9705
33.4545 50.0313
33.2465 49.9479
33.2997 50.0631
33.3753 49.9329
33.3551 49.9348
33.3637 49.9953
33.4096 49.8524
33.2912 49.9938
33.3920 50.0670
33.2756 50.0252
33.3362 50.0164
33.3194 49.9503
33.3875 50.0264
33.3577 50.0180
33.3177 49.9774
33.3241 49.9028
33.3430 50.0314
33.3529 49.9234
33.3736 50.0945
33.2709 50.0145
33.3959 49.9690
33.2584 49.9367
33.3439 49.9693
33.3177 50.0755
33.3352 50.0213
33.3520 50.0091
33.3847 49.9917
33.2689 49.9825
33.3152 50.0930
33.2931 49.9539
33.4135 49.9799
33.3074 49.9071
33.4124 50.0347
33.3376 49.9806
33.2958 50.0093
33.3670 49.9676
33.3406 50.0471
33.4185 49.9595
33.3918 50.0502
33.2201 49.8565
33.3835 50.0287
33.3018 49.9958
33.3916 49.9694
33.3064 49.9360
33.3786 50.0514
33.3674 49.9756
33.3168 50.0297
33.3914 50.1439
33.3369 50.0186
33.2750 50.0198
33.2537 49.9913
33.3132 49.9802
33.2756 50.0837
33.3086 50.0470
33.3639 49.9534
33.4414 49.9151
33.2555 49.8875
33.3687 49.9512
33.4125 50.0191
33.3503 50.0734
33.3872 49.9954
33.3778 50.0713
33.3119 50.0099
33.3403 50.0387
33.3547 49.9746
33.3022 49.9934
33.3649 49.9790
33.2675 50.0480
33.3151 50.0353
33.3058 49.9285
33.2726 50.0574
33.3726 49.8949
33.3167 49.9759
33.3880 50.0371
33.3568 49.9785
33.2936 50.0146
33.3387 49.9139
33.2805 50.0440
33.2645 50.0463
33.3883 49.9940
33.3344 50.0063
33.3417 50.0145
33.4604 49.9897
33.3531 49.9737
33.3573 49.9283
33.3183 49.9428
33.3374 50.0304
33.2600 49.9110
33.3737 49.9721
33.2409 50.0684
33.2383 50.0029
33.3314 49.9501
33.3217 49.9614
33.3137 50.0420
33.3107 50.0142
33.2871 49.9756
33.3327 50.0447
33.4156 50.0390
33.2507 50.0187
33.3133 49.9717
33.3107 49.9444
33.3100 50.0403
33.3600 49.9066
33.3474 49.9511
33.3196 49.9671
33.3158 50.0305
33.3170 50.0906
33.4040 49.9947
33.3707 50.0061
33.2544 49.9721
33.3308 49.9852
33.3680 49.9547
33.3154 49.9054
33.3647 50.0623
33.3650 49.9896
33.3641 50.0057
33.4218 50.0650
33.4237 49.9281
33.3714 49.8918
33.3307 50.0056
33.3222 50.0475
33.3442 50.0644
33.3329 50.1113
33.3311 49.9829
33.3615 49.8649
33.3784 50.0487
33.3163 49.9500
33.2803 50.0385
33.4251 49.9721
33.4025 49.9552
33.3128 49.9329
33.4071 49.9839
33.2633 49.9906
33.3411 50.0674
33.3992 50.1086
33.3162 49.9918
33.3134 50.0494
33.2594 50.0045
33.3662 49.9540
33.3906 49.9681
33.2827 50.0005
33.4336 50.0136
33.3626 50.0589
33.2965 50.0070
33.3397 49.9980
33.3810 50.0854
33.3388 49.9915
33.3286 49.9843
33.3377 50.0020
33.2919 50.0464
33.3267 49.9612
33.4178 50.0428
33.3233 49.9918
33.3572 50.0195
33.3525 50.0102
33.3370 49.9672
33.3553 49.9657
33.3143 50.0008
33.3196 50.0216
33.3161 50.0878
33.3437 50.0991
33.3522 50.0508
33.3919 50.0170
33.4058 50.0458
33.3811 49.9579
33.3353 50.0223
33.3790 49.9748
33.3537 50.0012
33.3074 50.0946
33.3862 50.0501
33.3149 49.9471
33.3277 49.9539
33.3604 50.0526
33.3232 49.9463
33.3443 50.0873
33.4148 49.9202
33.3724 49.9170
33.3848 50.0160
33.2894 49.9793
33.2868 49.9558
33.3127 49.9315
33.3310 50.0165
33.2895 49.9698
33.3509 49.9553
33.3664 50.0145
33.2926 50.0408
33.3043 49.9356
33.2586 50.0078
33.3388 49.9237
33.3677 49.9739
33.2725 49.9689
33.3247 50.0302
33.2767 50.0450
33.3263 50.0134
33.3736 49.9651
```

Comment: Nice nice, but why is there a curve between $33.22\%$ and $33.46\%$. I don't know why the curve is shifted. Maybe I have left out some important case in my finite probability. Anyways $33.33\%$ is kind of close to $31.25\%$, so maybe I am on to something.

Comment: By the way, could you do the same experiment with $3n+1$ instead of $\frac{3n+1}{2}$ in the odd case and share the resulting percentage? (Im not used to Pari/GP)

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy - at "...why...curve...?" : I don't know/have no idea, I'm currently just looking at the occuring statistical data. At "...3n+1..." : I'll see, I'll just update my answer with new picture. At " #binary" in my answer: did I get your concept correctly at all? I first thought you have a more complicated function in mind?

Comment: It's the Shortcut function im studying. The complicated bit is the way I study the local neighbourhood. I have $8$ different local inputs. And on the left-edge (i.e. the most significant bit neighbourhood) there are one-case where the bit length is increases for the next output. Hence $12.5\%$. Since $n/2$ happens I included this. I don't know if I calculate $12.5\%$ and $50\%$ to be $31.25\%$ is the right way to do it.

Comment: It is a "hybrid" kind of Cellular Automaton that computes the shortcut Collatz numbers. I regard this as equal to the Shortcut function because it computes the same numbers.